Is it Possible to Implement Token-based Authentication Based on User UPNs(m365 account without password) in a Web Application?
I'm developing a web application where I only have users' UPNs (User Principal Names). I need to obtain individual tokens for each user based on their UPN without prompting them with an additional login window. Since I do not have access to users' passwords, the goal of this authentication process is to enforce access restrictions to specific features based on each user's permissions. Is this feasible to implement?
Specifically, my goal is to restrict MS search API results to show only sites accessible to each user. I have considered issuing tokens individually due to limited resources. I'm curious if there are methods to accomplish this or if there are alternative approaches.
--- added
Now, I developed search function with graph search api. It bring all data from sharepoint. Because, I used the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory library to authenticate applications through Azure AD and obtain tokens using these classes. Consequently, this phenomenon involves querying and retrieving all data across the entire tenant.
I tried get a token by user's username and password. But, I can't get user's password. So, I need to find solution.
I refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp
and this is search api document is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files

"I need to obtain individual tokens for each user based on their UPN without prompting them with an additional login window" - this is not possible unless your application has been granted delegation privilege (which it shouldn't be, imo). Why can't you integrate with Entra? Is this on-prem or Azure/Cloud-y?

without prompting them with an additional login window -> then how can we know the current user? if you already had some other way to know the current user e.g. SSO, then you can easily know the user role/permission based on the user principal name indicating from your description. Then you can certainly create a custom token for this user. Just add a token-based authorization into your web application to validate the token then. Otherwize you have to have an authentication mechanism to let your application know the current user.

See bottom of following section : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute

I believe my explanation may have been insufficient and confusing. Currently, I am deploying a web solution where users can log in with IDs registered in Active Directory (AD), and I can retrieve their m365 accounts from the database. However, because each user has different sites they can access in SharePoint, I aim to restrict the search scope accordingly

The reason I want to avoid additional login prompts is for the sake of user experience (UX). Requiring users to log in twice can be cumbersome for them. Additionally, since user roles and permissions regarding SharePoint sites are not stored in the database, I am exploring new approaches.
Please let me know if I misunderstood or if more information is needed. Thank you.
